# How to install jquery in asp.net core mvc + electronNET?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, electron

my application using asp.net core mvc + ElectronNET error cannot file module jquery come when i electronize start (Open web site to window app). I tried to write "jquery": "2.2.1" in package.json (dir: application/application/obj/Host) then npm install but it doesn't working. How to solve this problem.

this is error in inspector

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and seams to be a problem with jquery instance. Just set NodeIntegration to false in WebPreferences. Please check this issue -> [github issue](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/issues/400)